# Facebook Fans Page Question: How to send email to fans?

Tags: facebook, email, facebook-page

Facebook Fans Page Question: How to send email to fans?

There is a "Send an Update to Fans" button, but it will only send messages to fans' "facebook inbox's update folder"

Is there anyway to send news to fans' email so that they can get the news from their mail box? (I'm not talking about facebook mailbox, but real email)

Many thanks for reading!

Comment: May be a subscription-based newsletter? Unfortunatelly, this is not as trendy as Facebook...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://developers.facebook.com/news.php?blog=1&story=355

well this can solve the email question for those applications' fans page...

Comment: The link is broken =/